# no notifications from calendar and reminders apps on Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Editon

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have "Reminder On Event" in the Calendar app and set reminders for notes in the Reminders app, but yet I receive no notifications from either app.

Where do I go wrong?

Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Editon - Ubuntu 14.10 (r20)

Kind regards
/eva

Comment: Did you enable notifications under System Settings > Notifications?

Comment: Thanks for  your reply!I have four items there: External Drives, System Settings,Reminders and Telegram. I have Notifications enabled for the first three.

Comment: Firstly, since a new update came in last week, update your phone if not yet done and check, if the issue is still existent. If it is still there: For the calendar app there are some bugs reported for not reminding before event, reminding on event but wrong time zone and one for not reminding at all. For me I get reminders on event, but not in advance. You might want to look on all bugs reported for the calendar app (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-calendar-app) and check if yours is already reported or report a bug yourself. There is no other setting I could think of related to notifications

Comment: My system is up to date. I did receive a notification from the calendar now (but it does not work the way I need it to), but still none from the Reminder app.

Comment: And thanks for helping out! Did not understand much from the bug reports though :)

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time the only thing that can be done to bring about a more feasible answer is to head over to launchpad and mark the the following bug as affecting you too and subscribe to it. Unless of course you feel like fixing the issue yourself. =) You may subscribe only to the notification mail when the bug is closed to avoid being flooded with technical details.

This will increase the 'heat' on this issue, so it may get fixed quicker:

[[calendar] Reminder notifications are not integrated into system notifications](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-calendar-app/+bug/1440111)